# INtegrate a working highcharter plot into a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to integrate the following into an App:

The code stores two plots into the global environment and I can't seem to access them via the Shiny App. My overall objective is to have this same output in a Shiny Application.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)

imap(unique(df$type), function(j, k) {                   # index & type in df
  plt <- df %>% filter(type == j) %>%                    # filter for the type
    hchart("point", regression = T,                      # add poly reg line
           regressionSettings = list(color = "red", type = "polynomial",
                                     hideInLegend = T),  # no legend
           hcaes(x = mts2, y = price)) %>% 
    hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js") %>%  # tie-in reg dep
    hc_xAxis(min = 5, max = 160, crosshair = T) %>%      # all w/ same x rng
    hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, crosshair = T)
  assign(paste0("plt", k), plt, envir = .GlobalEnv)      # add plot to env
})


browsable(tagList(
  tags$script(HTML("
  setTimeout(function() {                                   /* using id from div */
    $('#hc_container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
      var chart, point, i, event;
      for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {      /* loop through both charts */
          chart = Highcharts.charts[i];                     /* identify the chart */
          event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); /* find chart coordinates */
          point = chart.series[1].searchPoint(event, true); /* get closest point; reg line only */
          if (point) {                                      /* if point found, tip it */
              point.highlight(e);
          }
      }
    });
  }, 500);
  Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) { /* executes tooltip from trigger */
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);    /* capture that event occurred */
    this.onMouseOver();                                    /* show marker */
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);               /* show tooltip */
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); /* show crosshair */
  };
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {        /* vigilant tooltip */
    return null;
  };
")),
  div(id = "hc_container",     # this id is used in the JQuery/Javascript above
      div(plt1, style = 'height:50%; width: 100%;'), # first plot
      div(plt2, style = 'height:50%; width: 100%;'), # second plot
      style = "height:100%; width:100%;")))          # container styles
```

Shiny App (does not work):

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)


ui_MODULE <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  browsable(tagList(
    tags$script(HTML("
  setTimeout(function() {                                   /* using id from div */
    $('#hc_container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
      var chart, point, i, event;
      for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {      /* loop through both charts */
          chart = Highcharts.charts[i];                     /* identify the chart */
          event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); /* find chart coordinates */
          point = chart.series[1].searchPoint(event, true); /* get closest point; reg line only */
          if (point) {                                      /* if point found, tip it */
              point.highlight(e);
          }
      }
    });
  }, 500);
  Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) { /* executes tooltip from trigger */
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);    /* capture that event occurred */
    this.onMouseOver();                                    /* show marker */
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);               /* show tooltip */
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); /* show crosshair */
  };
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {        /* vigilant tooltip */
    return null;
  };
")),
    div(id = "hc_container",     # this id is used in the JQuery/Javascript above
        div(plt1, style = 'height:50%; width: 100%;'), # first plot
        div(plt2, style = 'height:50%; width: 100%;'), # second plot
        style = "height:100%; width:100%;")))          # container styles

}

server_MODULE <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){


    imap(unique(df$type), function(j, k) {                   # index & type in df
      plt <- df %>% filter(type == j) %>%                    # filter for the type
        hchart("point", regression = T,                      # add poly reg line
               regressionSettings = list(color = "red", type = "polynomial",
                                         hideInLegend = T),  # no legend
               hcaes(x = mts2, y = price)) %>%
        hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js") %>%  # tie-in reg dep
        hc_xAxis(min = 5, max = 160, crosshair = T) %>%      # all w/ same x rng
        hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, crosshair = T)
      assign(paste0("plt", k), plt, envir = .GlobalEnv)      # add plot to env
    })
  }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  ui_MODULE("regOutputModule")

)


server <- function(input, output) {

  server_MODULE("regOutputModule")

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Data:

```
df = structure(list(price = c(1600, 1200, 249000, 288000, 775000, 
350000, 715000, 330000, 375000, 925, 1250, 300000, 425000, 489000, 
1200, 550000, 1895, 310000, 289000, 450000, 1250, 288000, 1000, 
600, 1100, 350000, 1200, 339000, 405000, 427000, 299000, 218000, 
159900, 360000, 365000, 725, 405000, 300000, 715000, 1300, 1400, 
1500, 415000, 1500, 663, 350000, 365000, 230000, 515000, 259000, 
310000, 405000, 288000, 350000, 288000, 1300, 350000, 1350, 715000, 
350000, 715000, 185000, 2200, 288000, 353800, 290000, 229000, 
365000, 1900, 1300, 590000, 180000, 1050, 1900, 1100, 1950, 288000, 
1995, 112000, 369000, 593000, 550000, 365000, 715000, 1800, 713000, 
1100, 260000, 375000, 715000, 338000, 288000, 1900, 288000, 2800, 
2450, 1990, 260000, 415000, 745000), habs = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 
4, NA, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, NA, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 
4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
3, NA, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, NA, 4, 3), mts2 = c(70, 65, 
55, 76, 121, 87, 109, 85, 81, 46, 65, 55, 100, 102, 65, 122, 
66, 51, 85, 99, 50, 75, 55, 10, 75, 87, 71, 75, 83, 118, 85, 
57, 45, 112, 63, 40, 83, 75, 109, 91, 74, 58, 100, 75, 42, 82, 
90, 65, 104, 52, 55, 83, 79, 87, 76, 77, 87, 88, 109, 83, 109, 
46, 145, 76, 40, 66, 63, 90, 45, 65, 115, 44, 46, 45, 73, 90, 
79, 110, 42, 81, 73, 115, 94, 109, 70, 104, 75, 58, 80, 109, 
92, 79, 45, 76, 122, 160, 47, 58, 100, 104), type = c("alquiler", 
"alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"alquiler", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:

When I try to apply the function to some "dynamic" filtered data I get some errors:

I have the following:

```
server_filter_regressions <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      filteredData = reactive({
        data %>%
          filter(provincia == input$provinceSelect &
                   municipio == input$municipioSelect &
                   distrito == input$distritoSelect &
                   zona == input$zonaSelect
          )
      })
      
      observe(
        print(filteredData())
      )
      
      
      imap(unique(filteredData()$type), function(j, k) { # index & type in df
        output[[paste0("plt", k)]] <- renderHighchart({
          filteredData() %>%
            filter(type == j) %>% # filter for the type
            hchart("point",
                   regression = T, # add poly reg line
                   regressionSettings = list(
                     color = "red", type = "polynomial",
                     hideInLegend = T
                   ), # no legend
                   hcaes(x = mts2, y = price)
            ) %>%
            hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js") %>% # tie-in reg dep
            hc_xAxis(min = 5, max = 160, crosshair = T) %>% # all w/ same x rng
            hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, crosshair = T)
        })
      })
      
    }
  )
}
```

I get this error:

```
Masking (modules:highcharter):
  `%>%` from: modules:magrittr

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5715
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
  59: <Anonymous>
  58: signalCondition
  57: signal_abort
  56: rlang::abort
  55: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
  54: getCurrentContext
  53: .dependents$register
  52: filteredData
  46: module [server/serverRegressions.R#101]
  41: callModule
  40: moduleServer
  39: server_regressions$server_filter_regression [server/serverRegressions.R#81]
  38: server [/home/matt/Desktop/realEstate/Real Estate Analytica/RealEstate/app.R#180]
   1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
✔ The provincias were observed and the updateSelectInput was updated to provincias: 
 The NS id is:  filterPropertiesMainPage 
✔ After observing the selection of provincias, the municipios dropdown is updated: 
The NS id is: filterPropertiesMainPage
✔ The municipio dropdown was selected and now the distrito dropdown is update: 
.The NS id is: filterPropertiesMainPage
✔ The distrito dropdown was selected and now the zona dropdown is update: 
.The NS id is: filterPropertiesMainPage
# A tibble: 0 × 32
# … with 32 variables: price <dbl>, direccion <chr>, provincia <chr>, municipio <chr>, distrito <chr>, zona <chr>, collectionDate <date>, collectionTime <dttm>,
#   individualPropertyPageToCollect <chr>, habs <dbl>, baños <dbl>, mts2 <dbl>, Terraza <lgl>, Calefacción2 <lgl>, Planta2 <chr>, Tipo de inmueble <chr>, Antigüedad <chr>, Planta <chr>,
#   Parking <chr>, Amueblado <chr>, Estado <chr>, Ascensor <chr>, Orientación <chr>, Agua caliente <chr>, Calefacción <chr>, NA <lgl>, price_mts_sqrd <dbl>, type <chr>, Depósito <chr>,
#   Gastos de comunidad <chr>, Mascotas <chr>, Europe/Madrid <lgl>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

EDIT 2:

My structure and code looks like:

SERVER.R

```
server_filter_regressions <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns

      filteredData = reactive({
        data %>%
          filter(provincia == input$provinceSelect &
                   municipio == input$municipioSelect &
                   distrito == input$distritoSelect &
                   zona == input$zonaSelect
          )
      })

      observe(
        print(filteredData())
      )


      observe({imap(unique(filteredData()$type), function(j, k) { # index & type in df
        output[[paste0("plt", k)]] <- renderHighchart({
          filteredData() %>%
            filter(type == j) %>% # filter for the type
            hchart("point",
                   regression = T, # add poly reg line
                   regressionSettings = list(
                     color = "red", type = "polynomial",
                     hideInLegend = T
                   ), # no legend
                   hcaes(x = mts2, y = price)
            ) %>%
            hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js") %>% # tie-in reg dep
            hc_xAxis(min = 5, max = 160, crosshair = T) %>% # all w/ same x rng
            hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, crosshair = T)
        })
      })
      })

    }
  )
}
```

UI.R

```
ui_filter_regression <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
        setTimeout(function() {                                   /* using id from div */
          $('#hc_container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
            var chart, point, i, event;
            for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {      /* loop through both charts */
                chart = Highcharts.charts[i];                     /* identify the chart */
                event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); /* find chart coordinates */
                point = chart.series[1].searchPoint(event, true); /* get closest point; reg line only */
                if (point) {                                      /* if point found, tip it */
                    point.highlight(e);
                }
            }
          });
        }, 500);
        Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) { /* executes tooltip from trigger */
          event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);    /* capture that event occurred */
          this.onMouseOver();                                    /* show marker */
          this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);               /* show tooltip */
          this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); /* show crosshair */
        };
        Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {        /* vigilant tooltip */
          return null;
        };
      ")
    ),
    titlePanel("Highcharts"),
    div(
      id = "hc_container", # this id is used in the JQuery/Javascript above
      div(
        highchartOutput(ns("plt1")),
        style = "height:50%; width: 100%;"
      ), # first plot
      div(
        highchartOutput(ns("plt2")),
        style = "height:50%; width: 100%;"
      ), # second plot
      style = "height:100%; width:100%;"
    )
  )
}
```

Then I call it in the App:

ui_regressions <- modules::use("ui/uiRegressions.R")
server_regressions <- modules::use("server/serverRegressions.R")

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(

...

ui_regressions$ui_filter_regression("filterPropertiesMainPage")

...

)
),
 server = function(input, output) {
    server_regressions$server_filter_regression("filterPropertiesMainPage", data)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrapping the code from your interactive script in a shiny app or shiny modules will not work. In your interactive script you are creating the charts first in your global environment before displaying them. Basically you do the same with your shiny app. But as is, `plt1` and `plt2` do not exist when you start your app and you get an error when trying to call these objects in the UI.

Overall I see no reason to create the plots in the global environment. Instead I would suggest to create output objects in your server module using `renderHighchart` which could then be displayed in the ui using `highchartOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)

ui_MODULE <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
        setTimeout(function() {                                   /* using id from div */
          $('#hc_container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
            var chart, point, i, event;
            for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {      /* loop through both charts */
                chart = Highcharts.charts[i];                     /* identify the chart */
                event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); /* find chart coordinates */
                point = chart.series[1].searchPoint(event, true); /* get closest point; reg line only */
                if (point) {                                      /* if point found, tip it */
                    point.highlight(e);
                }
            }
          });
        }, 500);
        Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function(event) { /* executes tooltip from trigger */
          event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);    /* capture that event occurred */
          this.onMouseOver();                                    /* show marker */
          this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);               /* show tooltip */
          this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); /* show crosshair */
        };
        Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {        /* vigilant tooltip */
          return null;
        };
      ")
    ),
    titlePanel("Highcharts"),
    div(
      id = "hc_container", # this id is used in the JQuery/Javascript above
      div(
        highchartOutput(ns("plt1")),
        style = "height:50%; width: 100%;"
      ), # first plot
      div(
        highchartOutput(ns("plt2")),
        style = "height:50%; width: 100%;"
      ), # second plot
      style = "height:100%; width:100%;"
    )
  )
}

server_MODULE <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    imap(unique(df$type), function(j, k) { # index & type in df
      output[[paste0("plt", k)]] <- renderHighchart({
        df %>%
          filter(type == j) %>% # filter for the type
          hchart("point",
            regression = T, # add poly reg line
            regressionSettings = list(
              color = "red", type = "polynomial",
              hideInLegend = T
            ), # no legend
            hcaes(x = mts2, y = price)
          ) %>%
          hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js") %>% # tie-in reg dep
          hc_xAxis(min = 5, max = 160, crosshair = T) %>% # all w/ same x rng
          hc_tooltip(useHTML = T, crosshair = T)
      })
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_MODULE("regOutputModule")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  server_MODULE("regOutputModule")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly on a standalone app with the `df` data that I provided, however, when I want to add some filters the code breaks - I think its to do with the `filteredData()` in the `imap` part of the server. I am passing a `reactive` "()" to the plot but it is not working. Do you have any ideas? - I added the code and error to the original post.

Comment: The issue is that `unique(filteredData()$type` will not work outside of a reactive context. You haven't included the UI for the updated code so it's hard to check. But wrapping in an `observe` or an `observeEvent` triggered by `filteredData()` might be fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will try! - I did not make any modifications to the UI part of your code.

Comment: I added another edit to show a little more the strucutre of the code - I have a server and UI file which I call from the main App.